# Is it possible to convert carbon dioxide into a solid at low cost?

Tags: carbon-cycle, carbon

Is it possible to reduce the level of carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>) in the atmosphere by converting it into a solid, thus reducing the level of greenhouse gases?

Comment: Photosynthesis.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.rmit.edu.au/news/all-news/2019/feb/carbon-dioxide-coal#:%7E:text=The%20CO%202%20slowly%20converts%20into%20solid%20flakes,produced%20could%20also%20be%20used%20as%20an%20electrode.) in the press cites CO<sub>2</sub> has been converted  into Carbon at relative low temperature.

> The research team led by RMIT University in Melbourne, Australia, have developed a new technique that can efficiently convert CO2 from a gas into solid particles of carbon.

> To date, CO2 has only been converted into a solid at extremely high temperatures, making it industrially unviable.
>
> By using liquid metals as a catalyst, we’ve shown it’s possible to turn the gas back into carbon at room temperature, in a process that’s efficient and scalable.
>
> While more research needs to be done, it’s a crucial first step to delivering solid storage of carbon.

The study [is published in Nature Communications](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-08824-8#). They used cerium oxyde as catalyst to reduce the temperature of the reaction.

> ... which facilitates the electrochemical reduction of CO2 to layered
> solid carbonaceous species, at a low onset potential of −310 mV vs
> CO2/C

All these CO<sub>2</sub> sequestration issues are under investigation and will be implemented in the coming years by energy companies.

---

**Esrafilzadeh, D., Zavabeti, A., Jalili, R. et al. (2019)**: "Room temperature CO2 reduction to solid carbon species on liquid metals featuring atomically thin ceria interfaces." *Nat Commun* 10, 865. https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-019-08824-8